# "Unflatten" columns into rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

Imagine a very simple database schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Department
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    manager_employee_id INTEGER,
    loveliest_jumper_employee_id INTEGER
);
```

Here, the two `..._employee_id` columns in the `Department` table are foreign keys into the `Employee` table.

I'd like to get a list of employee information for all employees who are either managers or have the loveliest jumper in their department.

This would do:

```sql
SELECT Employee.* 
FROM Employee, Department 
WHERE Employee.id = Department.manager_employee_id
UNION
SELECT Employee.* 
FROM Employee, Department 
WHERE Employee.id = Department.loveliest_jumper_employee_id;
```

But it's a bit of a pain. In my case, there are actually four relevant foreign key columns, not just two, so it's even more redundant. Is there are simpler way to write this query?

Some extra points about my situation:

- Sometimes the foreign key could be NULL (i.e. no manager and/or no lovely jumpers at all in that department) and there should be no row in the result set for that.
- You can assume that there is no foreign key (except NULL) is listed in more than one row or column (no one is is more than one department ... and no managers have lovely jumpers).
- I don't need any information in the result set except the Employee table i.e. neither the department name nor the employee's relationship with the department (manager / lovely jumper wearer).

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Check out [Bad habbits](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) you really should have kicked by now

Comment: Oops, you're both right. **Except** I've just realised my question is trivial, I just need an "OR" in the WHERE condition... But that only works with my outdated syntax.

Comment: It works in the ON clause of a proper INNER JOIN also.

Comment: @ArthurTacca That's just not true. You certainly can use OR conditions with ansi JOINs.

Comment: ... Oops. I would self answer or just close but I'm no longer at a proper computer ATM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can also just use an `IN` clause:

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN Department d 
  ON e.id IN (d.manager_employee_id, d.loveliest_jumper_employee_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN Department d 
  ON e.id = d.manager_employee_id OR e.id = d.loveliest_jumper_employee_id;
```